In Windows, how to add and verify execution permission to a file?
Here is a typical situation, assuming that I am the user desktop-6083m7k\pengc running powershell:
PS D:\git\HMD-Air\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\VSWhere> whoami
desktop-6083m7k\pengc
PS D:\git\HMD-Air\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\VSWhere>
PS D:\git\HMD-Air\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\VSWhere> Get-Acl -Path .\vswhere.exe | Format-List


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::D:\git\HMD-Air\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\VSWhere\vswhere.exe
Owner  : DESKTOP-6083M7K\pengc
Group  : DESKTOP-6083M7K\pengc
Access : Everyone Deny  ExecuteFile
         Everyone Allow  DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  Modify, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership, Synchronize
         DESKTOP-6083M7K\pengc Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  Modify, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:S-1-5-21-3664606926-4282448695-284990962-1002G:S-1-5-21-3664606926-4282448695-284990962-1002D:AI(D;ID;WP;;;WD)(A;ID;0x1201ff;;;WD)(A;ID;0x1f01bf;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;S-1-5-21-3664606926-428244869
         5-284990962-1002)(A;ID;0x1f01bf;;;BA)



PS D:\git\HMD-Air\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\VSWhere> .\vswhere.exe
Program 'vswhere.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ .\vswhere.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\vswhere.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

PS D:\git\HMD-Air\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.22\Editor\VSWhere> whoami
desktop-6083m7k\pengc

According to Get-Acl, the file already has granted FullControl permission to me (which should include Execute permission in theory), but I still can't run it due to insufficient permission.
Why could this happen and how can I fix it?

The "why" is due to the Everyone Deny  ExecuteFile ACE.

Can you show the same ACL through icacls?
